# Nodejs: json api call before exit with sigint?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, exit, sigint

I am trying to set some variables and then do an api call with [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) before exiting the programm, but somehow the function is not executed because of `sigint` & `exit`:

```
const request = require('request')

['exit', 'SIGINT'].forEach(function(signal) {
    process.on(signal, function() {

        console.log('the following function is not executed properly')
        request.post(
            "url",
            { json: 
                {
                    "vara": vara,
                    "varb": varb,
                    "varc": varc
                } 
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body);
                }
            } 

        )
        process.exit();

    });
});
```

I also tried putting `process.exit()` inside the callback function, e.g. behind the `console.log()`, it doesn't work anyway, as if no async functions are executed inside to `process.on()`:

```
console.log(body);
process.exit();
```

What is the proper way to do it with the `request` library?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the execution of the request and the `process.exit()` are executed at the same time. You need to move this exit command in your callback to guarantee the good execution of the request.

Comment: Thx for the answer, I updated my question, unfortunately it doesn't work